# Jquery login with header for updating session not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session, header

I have made an attempt to make a login system using Jquery to check for clicking and then sending the posting to a php file. This file takes the results, checks the mysql database. If username and password isn't correct it echoes. If login is correct then it puts a user-id in sessions and tries to call header to update the session on the start file, but this won't work.

I must reload the page manually for the session the to update. Is this possible to change?

This is the index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='user'> 
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) echo "Logged in"; else echo "Not logged in"; 
    ?>
    </div>
    <center>
    <div id='login'>
        <div id='login-warning'></div>
        <input type='text' id='username' placeholder='Your name'>
        <input type='text' id='password' placeholder='Your password'>
        <input type='button' id='login-submit' value= 'Send'>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

This the javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input#login-submit').click(function() {
        var username = $('input#username').val();
        var password = $('input#password').val();
        $.post('login.php', {u: username, p: password}, function(data) {
                $('#login-warning').text(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This is the login.php file:

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST) === false) {

    $U = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9._]", "", $_POST['u']);
    $P = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9._]", "", $_POST['p']);

    if(empty($U) === true AND empty($P) === true) {
        $error = " You need to enter a username and password";
    } else if (empty($U) === false AND empty($P) === true) {
        $error = " You need to enter a password";
    } else if (empty($U) === true AND empty($P) === false) {
        $error = " You need to enter a username";
    } else if (empty($U) === false AND empty($P) === false) {


        require_once 'db_connect.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user='$U'" or die("Error.." . mysqli_error($db));
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user = $row['user'];
            $pass = $row['password'];
                            $active = $row['active'];
        }

        if (!$id) {
            $error = "User not found";
        } else {
            if ($P == $pass AND $P != "") {
                if ($active == 1) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user;
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
                    session_write_close();
                    //
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    //
                    ob_end_flush();
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $error = "You have not activated your account";
                }
            } else {
                $error = "Incorrect password";
            }
        }
    }

}

echo $error;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

your `index.php` is not updated with new register session, you can't use `header("location:index.php")` in ajax call, you must reload the page via javascript.

*login.php :*

```
if($active == 1) {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user;
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
   $error = false;
}
```

*index.php :*

```
$.post('login.php',
       {u: username, p: password},
       function(data) {
           if(!data) {
             location.reload(false)
           } else {
             $('#login-warning').text(data);
           }
       }
)
```